# How do I create a PHP based WebSocket server on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, websocket, phpwebsocket

This is Heroku's document https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets.

Is it possible to create a PHP based WebSocket server on Heroku?

Comment: already asked, but no answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329030
Google returns this: https://www.livecoding.tv/video/heroku-php-websocket-server/